# Why do I get white space at the bottom of my diagram?

Tags: tikz-pgf, standalone

I have this code :

```
\documentclass[tikz}]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,positioning,fit,calc,decorations,decorations.text,}
\begin{document}
\sffamily
\begin{tikzpicture}[
        white,
        ultra thick,
        planet/.style = {draw,fill,circle,inner sep=#1},
        circle label/.style = {
            postaction={
                decoration={
                    text along path,
                    text = {#1},
                    text align=center,
                    text color=white,
                    reverse path,
                },
            decorate,
        }
        }
    ]
    \filldraw[black] (-15,-3) rectangle (15,15);
    \node[rectangle, ] at (0, 13) {\color{white} \fontsize{25}{58}\selectfont LES {\'E}TOILES LES PLUS PROCHES DU SOLEIL};
    \path[circle label={Nuage d'Oort}] (0,-1.2) arc (-90:360-90:1.3);
    \draw[dotted] (0,0) circle (1.18596338615);

        \foreach \i in {3,6,9} {
            \path[circle label={\i\ ANN{\'E}S LUMI{\`E}RES}] (0,-\i-.2) arc (-90:360-90:\i+.2);
    }
    \draw (0,0) circle (3);
    \draw ([shift=(-30:6cm)]0,0) arc (-30:210:6cm);
    \draw ([shift=(-19.47:9cm)]0,0) arc (-19.47:199.47:9cm);

    \node[yellow,planet=3pt,label={Soleil}] at (0,0) {};

    \node(proxima)[red,planet=3pt] at (44:6.363) {};
     \node[text width=2.8cm,align=center, right = 0.05 of proxima] {Proxima Centauri.\newline(distance 1917)};

    \node[yellow,planet=4pt,label={[text width=2.5cm,align=center]Alpha Centauri.\ (distanse 1917)}] at (50:6.54735) {};

    \node[red!50!black,planet=2pt] at (54:9.75) {};

    \node[red!50!black,planet=2pt, label={[text width=2.7cm,align=center]WISE 1049-5319.\ (distanse 2013)}] at (57:9.75) {};

    \node(bernard)[red,planet=3pt] at (130:8.94435) {};
    \node[text width=2.8cm,align=center, left = 0.05 of bernard] {{É}toile de Barnard.\ (distanse 1916)};

    \node(wise)[red,planet=3pt] at (110:10.7625) {};
    \node[text width=2.8cm,align=center, right = 0.05 of wise] {WISE 0855–0714.\newline(distanse 2014)};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And I get this :

[image]

The problem is the white space below my figure. I thought that `standalone` include only the figure. How to remove this white space?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your problem lies in these lines.

```
\foreach \i in {3,6,9} {
    \path[circle label={\i\ ANN{\'E}S LUMI{\`E}RES}] (0,-\i-.2) arc (-90:360-90:\i+.2);
}
```

Because of this, the bounding box gets extended below.

[image]

Change those lines to

```
    \foreach \i in {3,6,9} {
        \path[circle label={\i\ ANN{\'E}S LUMI{\`E}RES}] (\i+0.2,0) arc (0:180:\i+.2);
}
```

[image]

Full code:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,positioning,fit,calc,decorations,decorations.text}
\begin{document}
\sffamily
\begin{tikzpicture}[
        white,
        ultra thick,
        planet/.style = {draw,fill,circle,inner sep=#1},
        circle label/.style = {
            postaction={
                decoration={
                    text along path,
                    text = {#1},
                    text align=center,
                    text color=white,
                    reverse path,
                },
            decorate,
        }
        }
    ]
    \filldraw[black] (-15,-3) rectangle (15,15);
    \node[rectangle,text=white,font=\fontsize{25}{58}\selectfont ] at (0, 13) {LES {\'E}TOILES LES PLUS PROCHES DU SOLEIL};
    \path[circle label={Nuage d'Oort}] (0,-1.2) arc (-90:360-90:1.3);
    \draw[dotted] (0,0) circle (1.18596338615);

        \foreach \i in {3,6,9} {
            \path[circle label={\i\ ANN{\'E}S LUMI{\`E}RES}] (\i+0.2,0) arc (0:180:\i+.2);
    }
    \draw (0,0) circle (3);
    \draw ([shift=(-30:6cm)]0,0) arc (-30:210:6cm);
    \draw ([shift=(-19.47:9cm)]0,0) arc (-19.47:199.47:9cm);

    \node[yellow,planet=3pt,label={Soleil}] at (0,0) {};

    \node(proxima)[red,planet=3pt] at (44:6.363) {};
     \node[text width=2.8cm,align=center, right = 0.05 of proxima] {Proxima Centauri.\newline(distance 1917)};

    \node[yellow,planet=4pt,label={[text width=2.5cm,align=center]Alpha Centauri.\ (distanse 1917)}] at (50:6.54735) {};

    \node[red!50!black,planet=2pt] at (54:9.75) {};

    \node[red!50!black,planet=2pt, label={[text width=2.7cm,align=center]WISE 1049-5319.\ (distanse 2013)}] at (57:9.75) {};

    \node(bernard)[red,planet=3pt] at (130:8.94435) {};
    \node[text width=2.8cm,align=center, left = 0.05 of bernard] {{É}toile de Barnard.\ (distanse 1916)};

    \node(wise)[red,planet=3pt] at (110:10.7625) {};
    \node[text width=2.8cm,align=center, right = 0.05 of wise] {WISE 0855–0714.\newline(distanse 2014)};
%\draw[thick,red] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can clip to the rectangle you use as background:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,positioning,fit,calc,decorations,decorations.text,}
\begin{document}
\sffamily
\begin{tikzpicture}[
        white,
        ultra thick,
        planet/.style = {draw,fill,circle,inner sep=#1},
        circle label/.style = {
            postaction={
                decoration={
                    text along path,
                    text = {#1},
                    text align=center,
                    text color=white,
                    reverse path,
                },
            decorate,
        }
        }
    ]
    \clip (-15,-3) rectangle (15,15);
    \filldraw[black] (-15,-3) rectangle (15,15);
    \node[rectangle, ] at (0, 13) {\color{white} \fontsize{25}{58}\selectfont LES {\'E}TOILES LES PLUS PROCHES DU SOLEIL};
    \path[circle label={Nuage d'Oort}] (0,-1.2) arc (-90:360-90:1.3);
    \draw[dotted] (0,0) circle (1.18596338615);

        \foreach \i in {3,6,9} {
            \path[circle label={\i\ ANN{\'E}S LUMI{\`E}RES}] (0,-\i-.2) arc (-90:360-90:\i+.2);
    }
    \draw (0,0) circle (3);
    \draw ([shift=(-30:6cm)]0,0) arc (-30:210:6cm);
    \draw ([shift=(-19.47:9cm)]0,0) arc (-19.47:199.47:9cm);

    \node[yellow,planet=3pt,label={Soleil}] at (0,0) {};

    \node(proxima)[red,planet=3pt] at (44:6.363) {};
     \node[text width=2.8cm,align=center, right = 0.05 of proxima] {Proxima Centauri.\newline(distance 1917)};

    \node[yellow,planet=4pt,label={[text width=2.5cm,align=center]Alpha Centauri.\ (distanse 1917)}] at (50:6.54735) {};

    \node[red!50!black,planet=2pt] at (54:9.75) {};

    \node[red!50!black,planet=2pt, label={[text width=2.7cm,align=center]WISE 1049-5319.\ (distanse 2013)}] at (57:9.75) {};

    \node(bernard)[red,planet=3pt] at (130:8.94435) {};
    \node[text width=2.8cm,align=center, left = 0.05 of bernard] {{É}toile de Barnard.\ (distanse 1916)};

    \node(wise)[red,planet=3pt] at (110:10.7625) {};
    \node[text width=2.8cm,align=center, right = 0.05 of wise] {WISE 0855–0714.\newline(distanse 2014)};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Clipped]

Comment: Why I sould add this? Why `standalone` doesn't crop my figure correctly?

Comment: You gave me an idea how to replace the arcs with circle and add only one instruction to the foreach loop. Thanks

Comment: @user230137 I don't know why. I just know it doesn't and this works around it. It happened to me the other day and this is how I ended up solving it. It seems that `standalone` crops to include all defined/used points. I created the issue by using controls which lay outside the drawn parts of the picture to define the shape of curved lines. `standalone` included the space where those control points were even though they were only control points and did not actually lie on any path - not even one I didn't draw. As to why, I'm not sure. I answered how to eliminate the space but not why. Sorry.

Comment: @user230137 (3 comments up) `standalone` doesn't crop your figure. It crops the _page_ to fit your figure. Of course in order to do this, it needs to know how big your figure is, and the way it knows that is from the bounding box. `standalone` knows nothing about how the bounding box of the figure is determined, so it is not "smart" (or rather "psychic") enough to tell that part of that bounding box doesn't actually have anything drawn in it. That's TikZ's job.

Comment: @DavidZ Do you know why control points which aren't actually on a path cause the bounding box to be extended? (I realise that's not `standalone`'s doing - thanks for clarifying that - but I'm curious as to why `tikz` includes them.) I can see why stuff on a path gets included in the OP's example but it seems odder that mere control points do.

Comment: @cfr these points aren't control points though. They _are_ on a path, just not a path that is drawn. In the basic layer (PGF), the commands to construct a path and draw it are separate, so when PGF constructs a path it doesn't know yet whether that path will get drawn. Of course the designers of PGF _could_ have decided to only update the bounding box when you draw or fill or shade or decorate or etc. a path, but that way you couldn't use an undrawn path to expand the bounding box if you wanted to. It's easier to just update the bounding box when the path is constructed.

Comment: @DavidZ Thanks. I understand that. But even if the points are *only* control points i.e. *not* on a path at all, the bounding box still seems to get extended to include them. At least, that was what I figured was happening in my case.

Comment: @cfr interesting, I didn't think that happened but I just did some tests and it appears you're right. That's not really the problem in this question though, since when you're drawing a circle (which I think is done using Bezier curves internally), the control points will always be within the bounding box of the circle itself.

Comment: @DavidZ Yes. I agree it is off-topic for this question. It is just that that's why I knew a way around the problem here but didn't understand why I needed the solution in my case. Since you obviously knew much more than me, I thought perhaps you would be able to satisfy my curiosity. Apologies for taking things off on a tangent.